# How are the values of these function variables used by PHPUnit at all?

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and noticed this interesting method in the `app/tests/TestCase.php` file:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $unitTesting = true;
    $testEnvironment = 'testing';
    return require __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/start.php';
}
```

Both `$unitTesting` and `$testEnvironment` are scoped to the function and should, in theory, be thrown away when the function completes...however, removing these variables causes errors in PHPUnit.

I'm trying to figure out how these variables are used, whether it's through some reflection magic or whatnot...any illumination would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe they are used in the file which get's included?

Comment: Remember that PHP `require` and similar functions work like C's `#include`—they just interpolate the file's contents directly where they're called.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yup, you are indeed correct. I hunted through some of the 'nested' `require`'s and found the usage in `vendor/laravel/Foundation/start.php`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable get used in the file which gets included!

Because be aware what `require` do!

As an example:

file1.php:

```
$foo = $unitTesting . $testEnvironment;
```

file2.php:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $unitTesting = true;
    $testEnvironment = 'testing';
    return require "file1.php";
}
```

So if the require is done file2 looks like this:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $unitTesting = true;
    $testEnvironment = 'testing';
    return $foo = $unitTesting . $testEnvironment;
}
```

So as you can see the variable can/almost have been used in the required file

Comment: Shouldn't your example be `return require 'file1.php';`?